# How to change RefersTo for named range?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a class `ValidationChanger`, with a method `changeNamedRangeAddress` that should change the `RefersTo` address for a named range.  However, my code is unexpectedly wrapping the new address in double quotes.

Class definition for `ValidationChanger` here:

```
'ValidationChanger

Sub changeNamedRangeAddress(bk As Workbook, rangeName As String, newAddress As String)
 bk.Names(rangeName).RefersTo = newAddress
End Sub
```

I test it on a range named `TestRange`, which refers to an address in sheet `Instructions`: `Instructions!$A$133:$A$138`.  My test should change the address to `Instructions!$A$133:$A$139` with the following:

```
Sub testValidationChanger()

Dim vc As New ValidationChanger
Dim bk As Workbook

Set bk = Workbooks("test.xlsm")
Debug.Print bk.Names("TestRange").RefersTo
vc.changeNamedRangeAddress bk, "TestRange", "Instructions!$A$133:$A$139"
Debug.Print bk.Names("TestRange").RefersTo

End Sub
```

The output is:

```
=Instructions!$A$133:$A$138
="Instructions!$A$133:$A$139"
```

Any idea why the new address is wrapped in double quotes (which makes it function as a text string instead of an address)?

Comment: Pass the new range as a range object, and not as a string. `vc.changeNamedRangeAddress bk, "TestRange",[Instructions!$A$133:$A$139]`

Comment: @TimWilliams, that solves it.  I'll accept this if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the new range as a range object, and not as a string:

```
vc.changeNamedRangeAddress bk, "TestRange",[Instructions!$A$133:$A$139]
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you got a text string is that you did not preface the text string with an = sign (so that Excel would know it was supposed to be a formula)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a named range instead of the addresses then you can alter that named range to adapt to whatever you want.

```
'this line creates the name that you can use in formulas in 
'much the same way as "Instructions!$A$133:$A$139"
thisworkbook.Names.Add Name:="examplerange", RefersTo:=Range("A1:A5")

'this line changes what it's pointing to
thisworkbook.Names("exampleRange").RefersTo = Range("A1:A10")
```

Comment: Hello Carlos. Thanks for your answer. You may use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your answer and make it easier to understand.

Comment: @DiegoMalone did it - much better now :)